# URL Rewrite without file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, url-routing

I'm rewriting url rule in web.config file, but the rule does not work when using without aspx extension.
Web config looks like this

```
<configuration>
   <modulesSection>
        <rewriteModule>
           <rewriteOn>true</rewriteOn>
            <rewriteRules>
               <rule source="CaseDetails/(.*).aspx" destination="Client/Cases/CaseDetails.aspx" />
               <rule source="ArticleDetails/(.*).aspx" destination="Client/Articles/ArticleDetails.aspx" />
            </rewriteRules>
       </rewriteModule>
   </modulesSection>
</configuration>
```

But I want to write it in such a way that .aspx should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below in the **web.Config** file:

```
<system.web>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
        <add url="~/Default" mappedUrl="~/Default.aspx?name=hello&id=6"/>
    </urlMappings>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Can't we do it by updating the provided tags in web.config, bcz nothing seems to work if written outside the tag.

Comment: What do you mean by outside the tag?

Comment: I mean, not inside system.web but inside <configuration>
 <modulesSection>
See my question, there are some restrictions and that's why I have to write it inside <configuration>
 <modulesSection>